# Importing through a module file gives undefined for first event queue

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

I've got a React project where I keep all components available through a single file, so instead of doing

```
import Foo from "./Foo.js"
import Bar from "./Bar.js"
```

I've got a `components.js`-file with

```
export Foo from "./Foo.js"
export Bar from "./Bar.js"
```

so I can do

```
import { Foo, Bar } from "./components.js"
```

My problem is that `Foo`, `Bar`, and anything else I import this way is `undefined` for the first "event queue", that is, if I have this file

```
import { Foo, Bar } from "./components.js"

console.log("FOO1", !!Foo, !!Bar)
window.setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("FOO2", !!Foo, !!Bar)
}, 0)
```

it will output

```
FOO1 false false
FOO2 true true
```

This hasn't caused any trouble for with plain React components (functions nor classes), but when I try to use Redux's `connect`-function to create a container component, it complains about the input being `undefined`. I *guess* this is because when I declare React components, the references aren't, well, referenced directly, but when I call the `connect`-function, it immediately tries to access the component and sees that it's `undefined`. This is just my uneducated hypothesis though.

Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?
I thought it might've been a problem with the Stage 1 [transform-export-extensions plugin](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-export-extensions/), but I've used different syntax - e.g. `export const Foo = require("./Foo").default` - in `components.js` and the problem persists.

Comment: How are you loading these files (webpack, node, something else)? How are `Foo` and `Bar` exported by their original modules?

Comment: Usually this means you have some circular dependencies, so your code is executing before they have actually been exported.

Comment: @ssube I'm bundling it all up with Webpack to be used through a browser.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thank you, I'll look into that and see if I can find something obvious.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Yeah, looks like you were right. The problems seem to stem from the fact that the things I'm exporting from `components.js` also import stuff from `components.js`. Any idea if there's a way to solve this and still have a module file?

Comment: You'd need to rearrange your files so that things rely on eachother in a non-circular way.